# Generating multiple rows from one row in SQL based on a column

Tags: sql, datetime, teradata, recursive-query

I have a table with these five columns:

[image]

The `ID` is the PI here. `BEGIN_WINDOW` and `END_WINDOW` are `TIMESTAMP` columns. The `DURATION_DAYS_RUP` is calculated by dividing `DURATION_HRS` by 24 and rounding up.

What I'm trying to do is based on the `DURATION_DAYS_RUP`, I need to create multiple rows.

- If that value is 1, then the row created is just the same row with same ID, `BEGIN_WINDOW` and `END_WINDOW`.
- If it's greater than 1, for ex. 2, two rows would be created - one row where the `ID` is the same, `BEGIN_WINDOW` is the value from the original row, and `END_WINDOW` is 24 hrs + `BEGIN_WINDOW` and the second row would be the same `ID`, `BEGIN_WINDOW` is the `END_WINDOW` of that first row, and `END_WINOW` is this row's BEGIN_WINDOW + 24 hours.

See the example below:

[image]

I've researched a lot but can't seem to find the trick to doing this. If anyone has an idea, would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Teradata's [`EXPAND ON` syntax](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/2_MC9vCtAJRlKle2Rpb0mA/mGTn1U7447PPxB52l5xONQ):

```
SELECT x.ID, BEGIN(pd) as BEGIN_WINDOW, BEGIN(pd) + INTERVAL '24' HOUR as END_WINDOW
FROM mytable x
EXPAND ON PERIOD(x.BEGIN_WINDOW, x.END_WINDOW) AS pd
BY INTERVAL '24' HOUR;
```

Comment: This is much simpler than the recursive query. I did not know that Teradata had such feature.

Comment: Wow that is incredible, thank you! Also thank you @GMB for your query - also good to know

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte (id, begin_window, end_window, duration_days_rup) as (
    select 
        id, 
        begin_window, 
        case when duration_days_rup = 1 then end_window else begin_window + interval '1' day end,
        duration_days_rup - 1
    from mytable 
    union all
    select 
        id, 
        begin_window + interval '1' day,
        case when duration_days_rup = 1 then end_window else end_window + interval '1' day end, 
        duration_days_rup - 1
    from cte
    where duration_days_rup > 0
)
select id, begin_window, end from cte
```

Looking at your query, I doubt that you really need the `duray_days_rup` column, which is derived information. We could use straight date comparisons. I think the logic you want is:

```
with recursive cte (id, begin_window, end_window, real_end_window) as (
    select 
        id, 
        begin_window, 
        least(end_window, begin_window + interval '1' day),
        end_window
    from mytable 
    union all
    select 
        id, 
        begin_window + interval '1' day,
        least(real_end_window, end_window + interval '1' day),
        real_end_window
    from cte
    where begin_window + interval '1' day > real_end_window
)
select id, begin_window, end from cte
```